# How is @{push} different from @{u} or a tracking branch?

Tags: git

According to Git 2.5.0 release notes:

> A new short-hand `<branch>@{push}` denotes the remote-tracking branch that tracks the branch at the remote the  would be pushed to.

How is this different from `<branch>@{u}` (for upstream branch), or even just doing `$ git push` with no parameters when a proper tracking branch is set?

Comment: Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), simplifies a "[triangular workflow setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72403505/6309)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the relevant documentation, from `git help rev-parse`:

> ```
>        <branchname>@{push}, e.g. master@{push}, @{push}
>        The suffix @{push} reports the branch "where we would push to" if
>        git push were run while branchname was checked out (or the current
>        HEAD if no branchname is specified). Since our push destination is
>        in a remote repository, of course, we report the local tracking
>        branch that corresponds to that branch (i.e., something in
>        refs/remotes/).
>
>        Here's an example to make it more clear:
>
>            $ git config push.default current
>            $ git config remote.pushdefault myfork
>            $ git checkout -b mybranch origin/master
>
>            $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{upstream}
>            refs/remotes/origin/master
>
>            $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{push}
>            refs/remotes/myfork/mybranch
>
>        Note in the example that we set up a triangular workflow, where we
>        pull from one location and push to another. In a non-triangular
>        workflow, @{push} is the same as @{upstream}, and there is no need
>        for it.
> ```

So, they will be different if your upstream tracking branch is on a different remote than the one you've configured to push to by default.