# How to set up branches with different pull/push upstreams

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-fork

I have a local git repo with two remotes: `upstream`, the original main repo, and `origin`, my GitHub fork of it.

I want to create new branches based off of `upstream/master`, push them to `origin` for PRs, and periodically pull in new changes from `upstream/master`.

Is there a way to set up my branches so that this happens by default? I.e.:

```
$ git checkout -b my-new-branch --some-other-flags
$ git maybe some other command
# branch 'my-new-branch' points to 'upstream/master' and is checked out
# make changes, git commit
$ git push  # pushes to origin/my-new-branch
$ git pull  # pulls from upstream/master
```

Comment: [Git 2.37 (Q3 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72403505/6309) illustrates how a triangular workflow is set up.

Answer (score 8):

The following seems to work:

`git config push.default current && git config remote.pushdefault origin`

Then, create branches with `git checkout -b new-branch upstream/master`.

`git push` pushes to `origin/my-branch`, `git pull` pulls from `upstream/master`.

---

For branches based on other local branches instead of upstream/master, things seem a bit trickier. I could `git config branch.autoSetupMerge always`, but then branches would pull from the local branch they started from, not `upstream/master`. Or I could set the upstream to `upstream/master` explicitly with `-u` when creating the branch. I'm not sure which would be more appropriate though.

Another annoyance is that when I checkout a branch with changes, git sometimes tells me:

> Your branch is ahead of 'upstream/master' by 7 commits. (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

But A) it's fine that I'm ahead of my upstream, I'm waiting to merge these changes in a PR, and B) more importantly, `git push` will push to `new-branch` at *origin*, not `master` at upstream.

This doesn't always happen though, so I think there's some other variable I'm missing here.

Comment: Since you solved the problem, you can mark your own answer. It will benefit others who have similar questions.

Comment: I'm still not quite happy with my solution. It seems to work sometimes but has some edges I need to work out.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to set up my **branches** so that this happens by default?

No: you get only one "upstream" or `@{u}` setting per branch (you can have a branch with *no* upstream set, if you like, but your other option is *one* upstream).  `git fetch` fetches from the the remote in this upstream and `git merge` merges with the branch named in this upstream (and as usual, `git pull` essentially equals fetch + merge); `git push` pushes ... well, now things get complicated.

> Is there a way to set up my **repository** so that this happens by default?

Yes, but with a flaw.  How big this flaw is depends on your usage and needs.  Using (and configuring) this flaw is extra-complicated.  Let's run through the items.

Each local branch can have only one upstream, but:

- The upstream names two parts.  One is a *remote* like `origin` or `upstream`; the other is a *merge* like `refs/heads/master`.

These get combined to make `origin/master`, for instance.  So we're already out of luck with having the default upstream be both `origin/master` and `anything/my-new-branch`, whether or not the *`anything`* is `origin`.

But:

- You can configure Git for a "triangular workflow" where you fetch from one URL but push to another, by setting *two* URLs for any one given remote.

This means you can make some remote, let's call it `tri` for triangular, fetch from the URL you have for `origin` and push to the one you have for `upstream`.  If branch *B* has `tri` as its remote, and `tri` fetches from the same URL as `origin` but pushes to the same URL as `upstream`, then you will, in effect, fetch from `origin` and push to `upstream`.

Your Git will be a little confused, though, as to what `refs/remotes/tri/master` *means*.  If a push of the form:

```
git push tri somebranch:master
```

succeeds, your Git now thinks that `refs/remotes/tri/master` has the same hash you just pushed.  Your Git thinks: *Well, sure!  The guy I called up under `tri` says he took it!*  Once you run `git fetch tri` you'll get some other hash and your Git will fix this up to remember what's on the same URL as `origin` again.  Your Git thinks: *Well, that's funny, the guy I called up under `tri` says he has reset his `master`.  Oh well, that's the other Git for you, resetting his `master` all the time...*

Furthermore, when you run `git push tri` or `git push` with `tri` implied, but no *refspec* arguments on the command line ... well, this comes from [the `git push` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html):

> If `git push [<repository>]` without any `<refspec>` argument
>    is set to update some ref at the destination with `<src>` with
>    `remote.<repository>.push` configuration variable, `:<dst>` part can be
>    omitted—such a push will update a ref that `<src>` normally updates
>    without any `<refspec>` on the command line. Otherwise, missing
>    `:<dst>` means to update the same ref as the `<src>`.

This means you can set a special `remote.tri.push` configuration, so that `git push tri` without naming a source, or `git push tri somebranch` without naming `:<dst>`, you can make `somebranch` map to `somebranch` here, even if the one-upstream-setting you are allowed *for* `somebranch` says `master`.

#### Putting these all together

- You only get one `@{u}`.
- But that `@{u}` has two parts, a *remote* and a *merge*.
- Your `@{u}` can name a special remote that has two URLs: one for fetching, and a second for pushing.
- This remote can also have a `remote.remote.pushdefault` that forces the push `:dst` part to go to a different name than the fetch's *merge* setting.  (Let's call this *pushtarget* for the last point.)
- The side effect is that the remote-tracking branch `specialremote/pushtarget` will become wrong until you run `git fetch specialremote`.  This will make things confusing, as if they weren't already confusing because of all of the above.

If you ask me whether doing the above is a *good idea*, I will say: **definitely not**.

Comment: Just to underscore that this is a misuse of git: "Note that the push URL and the fetch URL, even though they can be set differently, must still refer to the same place. What you pushed to the push URL should be what you would see if you immediately fetched from the fetch URL. If you are trying to fetch from one place (e.g. your upstream) and push to another (e.g. your publishing repository), use two separate remotes." https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emset-urlem

Answer (score 1):

The new solution for a triangular workflow (pull from one branch, push to another) would be:

```
git config --global merge.autosetupmerge=true  # pull from origin/master
git config push.default current                # push to origin/feature1
git switch -c feature1 origin/master
```

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), "[`git -c branch.autosetupmerge=simple branch $A $B`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f49c478f628910de206c5e882a3cd3abec76d4e6/Documentation/git.txt#L77)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt))</sup>" will set the `$B` as `$A`'s upstream only when `$A` and `$B` shares the same name, and "`git -c push.default=simple`" on branch `$A` would push to update the branch $A at the remote `$B` came from.
Also more places use the sole remote, if exists, before defaulting to '`origin`'.

See [commit 05d5775](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05d57750c66e4b58233787954c06b8f714bbee75), [commit 8a649be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a649be7e8010085a8a3f1c9126da5c02324350e), [commit bdaf1df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdaf1dfae71fdf120fc7253e713ccf0a06cc5558) (29 Apr 2022) by [Tao Klerks (`TaoK`)](https://github.com/TaoK).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f49c478](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f49c478f628910de206c5e882a3cd3abec76d4e6), 26 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdaf1dfae71fdf120fc7253e713ccf0a06cc5558): new `autosetupmerge` option '`simple`' for matching branches
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tao Klerks</sup>

> With the default `push.default` option, "`simple`", beginners are protected from accidentally pushing to the "wrong" branch in centralized workflows: if the remote tracking branch they would push to does not have the same name as the local branch, and they try to do a "default `push`", they get an error and explanation with options.
>
> There is a particular centralized workflow where this often happens: a user branches to a new local topic branch from an existing remote branch, eg with "`checkout -b feature1 origin/master`".
>
> Problem:
>
> With the default `branch.autosetupmerge` configuration (value "`true`"), git will automatically add `origin/master` as the upstream tracking branch.
>
> When the user pushes with a default "[`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bdaf1dfae71fdf120fc7253e713ccf0a06cc5558/Documentation/git-push.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup>, with the intention of pushing their (new) topic branch to the remote, they get an error, and (amongst other things) a suggestion to run "`git push origin HEAD`".
>
> If they follow this suggestion the push succeeds, but on subsequent default pushes they continue to get an error - so eventually they figure out to add "`-u`" to change the tracking branch, or they spelunk the `push.default` config doc as proposed and set it to "`current`", or some GUI tooling does one or the other of these things for them.
>
> When one of their coworkers later works on the same topic branch, they don't get any of that "weirdness".
> They just "[`git checkout feature1`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bdaf1dfae71fdf120fc7253e713ccf0a06cc5558/Documentation/git-checkout.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))</sup> and everything works exactly as they expect, with the shared remote branch set up as remote tracking branch, and push and pull working out of the box.
>
> The "stable state" for this way of working is that local branches have the same-name remote tracking branch (`origin/feature1` in this example), and multiple people can work on that remote feature branch at the same time, trusting "[`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bdaf1dfae71fdf120fc7253e713ccf0a06cc5558/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> to merge or rebase as required for them to be able to push their interim changes to that same feature branch on that same remote.
>
> (merging from the upstream "`master`" branch, and merging back to it, are separate more involved processes in this flow).
>
> Problem (bis):
>
> There is a problem in this flow/way of working, however, which is that the first user, when they first branched from `origin/master`, ended up with the "wrong" remote tracking branch (different from the stable state).
>
> For a while, before they pushed (and maybe longer, if they don't use `-u`/`--set-upstream`), their "`git pull`" was *not* getting other users' changes to the feature branch - it was getting any changes from the remote "`master`" branch instead (a completely different class of changes!)
>
> An experienced Git user might say well yeah, that's what it means to have the remote tracking branch set to `origin/master`!" - but the original user above didn't *ask* to have the remote `master` branch added as remote tracking branch - that just happened automatically when they branched their feature branch.
> They didn't necessarily even notice or understand the meaning of the "set up to track '`origin/master`'" message when they created the branch - especially if they are using a GUI.
>
> Looking at how to fix this, you might think "OK, so disable auto setup of remote tracking - set `branch.autosetupmerge` to false" - but that will inconvenience the *second* user in this story - the one who just wanted to start working on the topic branch.
> The first and second users swap roles at different points in time of course - they should both have a sane configuration that does the right thing in both situations.
>
> Make this "branches have the same name locally as on the remote" workflow less painful / more obvious by introducing a new **`branch.autosetupmerge`** option called "`simple`", to match the same-name "`push.default`" option that makes similar assumptions.
>
> This new option automatically sets up tracking in a *subset* of the current default situations: when the original ref is a remote tracking branch *and* has the same branch name on the remote (as the new local branch name).
>
> Update the error displayed when the 'push.default=simple' configuration rejects a mismatching-upstream-name default push, to offer this new `branch.autosetupmerge` option that will prevent this class of error.
>
> With this new configuration, in the example situation above, the first user does *not* get `origin/master` set up as the tracking branch for the new local branch.
> If they "`git pull`" in their new local-only branch, they get an error explaining there is no upstream branch - which makes sense and is helpful.
> If they "`git push`", they get an error explaining how to push *and* suggesting they specify `--set-upstream` - which is exactly the right thing to do for them.
>
> This new option is likely not appropriate for users intentionally implementing a "**triangular workflow**" with a shared upstream tracking branch, that they "`git pull`" in and a private feature branch that they push/force-push to just for remote safe-keeping until they are ready to push up to the shared branch explicitly/separately.
> Such users are likely to prefer keeping the current default `merge.autosetupmerge=true` behavior, and change their `push.default` to "`current`".

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bdaf1dfae71fdf120fc7253e713ccf0a06cc5558/Documentation/config/branch.txt#L12-L14):

> ### `branch.autoSetupMerge`
>
> **`simple`** -- automatic setup is done only when the starting point
> is a remote-tracking branch and the new branch has the same name as the remote branch.
> This option defaults to true.

`git branch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bdaf1dfae71fdf120fc7253e713ccf0a06cc5558/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L224-L234):

> ### `-t / --track[=(direct|inherit)]`
>
> The `branch.autoSetupMerge` configuration variable specifies how `git switch`,
> `git checkout` and `git branch` should behave when neither `--track` nor
> `--no-track` are specified:
>
> - The default option, `true`, behaves as though `--track=direct`
>   were given whenever the start-point is a remote-tracking branch.
> - `false` behaves as if `--no-track` were given. `always` behaves as though
>   `--track=direct` were given.
> - `inherit` behaves as though `--track=inherit`
>   were given.
> - `simple` behaves as though `--track=direct` were given only when
>   the start-point is a remote-tracking branch and the new branch has the same
>   name as the remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the branch, you'll need to push it upstream and set it so your `local` can keep track of the `remote`.

You can do this as follows (assuming you're already in the master branch):

```
// Create and checkout the new branch
git checkout -b <your_branch_nane>

// Push new branch upstream and set it to track remote branch
git push -u origin <your_branch_name>
```

This will push your new branch upstream; the `-u` argument sets it to track the remote branch. The `-u` argument is just a shortcut for the `--set-upstream` argument.

You can read more about [working with remote branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to approach this.  I think what you probably want is to adopt a workflow that looks like this:

1. Start working on a new branch based on the upstream master:

   ```
   git checkout -b my-new-branch upstream/master
   ```
2. Make your changes, and configure the branch to push to your remote repository:

   ```
   git push -u origin my-new-branch
   ```

   (Subsequently you can just run `git push` by itself and changes will be sent to **your** repository)
3. When you want to bring in new changes from upstream:

   ```
   git remote update
   git rebase upstream/master
   ```

This allows you to periodically bring in new changes from upstream while preserving a linear history (rather than one littered with merge commits), which simplifies things in the event that you want to submit changes back to upstream.

Comment: This is basically what I'm doing now, I'm just interested in seeing if there are flags/configs I can set to make this happen by default without remembering as many individual steps.