# Convenient way to push to a pull request opened by someone else

Tags: git, github, git-branch, pull-request

I'm a maintainer of a project on a GitHub and we continuously get PRs. Usually I use the commands shown by GitHub to get and test the PR:

```
git checkout -b USER-master master
git pull https://github.com/USER/REPO.git master
```

However, when I want to push a commit I need to type:

```
git push https://github.com/USER/REPO.git USER-master:master
```

I was about to create an alias which can be used like

```
git pr https://github.com/USER/REPO.git master
```

It created a new branch (as GitHub suggests) and set that branch tracking the upstream of the PR. It'd allow to simple call `git push`.

To set the tracking branch I've tried:

```
git branch -u https://github.com/USER/REPO.git/master
```

And got:

```
error: the requested upstream branch 'https://github.com/USER/REPO.git/master' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

I assume that the many `/` in the remote's name confuses git as the branch is also separated by a `/`.

It could worked if I added a new remote with

```
git remote add USER-REPO https://github.com/USER/REPO.git
```

but I'd like to avoid adding so many remotes.

Any ideas on the `git branch -u`?

Comment: You can also, with Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), see "[How to set up branches with different pull/push upstreams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72403505/6309)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You'll probably want to set up more than one remote.  Once you do, though, things get messy.  When and whether to set the upstream of a local branch you made from a PR is up to you; you might not want to do that at all.  How fancy you want to make any of your scripts is also up to you.  You may end up with a so-called *triangular workflow*.

#### Long

This is a bit complicated, so let's start with this: the `-u` option to `git push` sets an *upstream*.  Each branch name in your own repository can have one (1) upstream, or no upstream at all; those are your only options.

Git's terminology (and GitHub's for that matter) gets confusing here.  The upstream I'm talking about above is a *branch* setting; `git branch --set-upstream-to` sets this setting; `git branch --unset-upstream` removes this setting.  In all cases, this setting applies to a *branch name* in *your repository*, e.g., in a repository on your laptop.  This is a local repository, not one on GitHub.

When we use GitHub, we get things called *pull requests*.  These are not part of Git itself!  Git has a command, `git request-pull`, but it just generates an email message.  It doesn't even *send* the email message, it just prints one out, suitable for you to put into some email-generating software.  So GitHub pull requests are *specific to GitHub*.

When we do *get* pull requests, though, we often want our own Git, on our laptop, working with *our* repository, to connect *to* GitHub.  We may store a copy of *our* repository on GitHub: `https://github.com/me/my.git` or whatever.  We tend to call this `origin`, as that's the first standard *remote*.

We already have three or four bits of terminology:

- *branch name:* this is a name for a commit.  Each repository, wherever it is stored, has *its own* branch names.  A branch name in *your* repository on your laptop has one special feature, which is that when you use it with `git checkout` or `git switch`, you wind up *on the branch*.  What this means is that as you make new commits, Git stores, into this branch-name, the *new* commit hash ID.  The new commit links backwards, in the usual way that commits do, to what *was* the latest commit, before you just made a new one.
- *upstream:* this is a string associated with a branch name in our (laptop) repository.  It's actually a two-part string—we'll see more on this later—but we usually see it as a simple string, like `origin/main` for `main`, `origin/master` for `master`, and `origin/feature/tall` for `feature/tall`.
- *remote:* This is simply a name for a URL.  The word `origin`, which appears in our upstream settings for our branches, is the first standard remote.  The URL stored under `origin` is typically that for our copy of some Git repository (the one we own or maintain directly), which is typically on some hosting site these days (GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, whatever).
- *pull request* or for GitLab, *merge request:* a hosted-site method by which someone can ask us, as the owner or maintainer of a repository, to put new commits into our hosted repository.  The details here vary depending on the hosting site.  Because you're using GitHub, I will use GitHub in the examples here.

Now we get to add *more* terminology.  Because people contributing to open-source software tend not to have push access *to* the maintainer's repository, they will use GitHub *forks*.  A GitHub fork is a server-side `git clone` operation that secretly<sup>1</sup> saves a lot of disk space on GitHub.  Meanwhile, using a fork gives *you*, as the user *of* the fork, a feature that you can't get otherwise.  Note that the pronoun *you* here actually refers to *some other person;* let's say it's a "he" and call him Fred.  *You* are the maintainer, so Fred creates a fork of *your* GitHub-side repository—the one you call `origin`—and Fred then uses *his fork* to do his work.

Eventually, Fred pushes some new commit(s) to Fred's GitHub repository, `ssh://git@github.com/fred/repo.git` or whatever.  *You* now want to *get* these commits, so that you can inspect them closely.<sup>2</sup>

You need your *laptop Git* to be able to refer to *Fred's fork*.  This isn't `origin`—that's *your* fork—so you need to use another URL.  You can, as you have been doing, type in the raw URL each time: `https://github.com/fred/repo.git` or whatever.

Don't do that!  It's a pain.  You'll make typos.  Well, maybe do it if it's a one-time thing, but if you find that you have to refer to Fred's fork a lot, create another *remote*.

Now, GitHub encourage us, for some reason,<sup>3</sup> to use the name `upstream` as the *second* standard remote name here.  That word is already a bit of terminology.  You *can* use it, but I suggest that you don't, as it just gets confusing.  Since we're talking about Fred here, let's use the name `fred` for this remote:

```
git remote add fred https://github.com/fred/repo.git
```

You can now use `fred` anywhere you were using `https://github.com/fred/repo.git`.  That may be encouragement enough—but this *also solves your issue*.

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't really *secret*, but you don't have to know about it.

<sup>2</sup>You could use GitHub's inspection options, but sometimes they're inadequate.  See any of Linus Torvald's complaints, for instance.  Sometimes they are good enough, and in those cases, using them really simplifies your job, so consider using them.  But here we won't do that.

<sup>3</sup>The reason is mostly that the "us" GitHub is trying to get through to are the amateurs who are making forks and contributing just one thing back.  Unfortunately, by using the word `upstream` here, they're doing us a big disservice.

---

#### Using multiple remotes allows setting upstreams

The reason that:

> ```
> git branch -u https://github.com/USER/REPO.git/master
> ```

failed is that the *upstream* of a branch is made up of two parts:

- First, there's the *remote* part.  This has to be an actual *remote*.
- After that there's a branch part.  This is the *name of the branch as seen on that remote Git*.

The two parts are separated by a slash.  Putting these two parts together gives us something that *looks like* a *remote-tracking name*.  Since we tend to copy *their* branches (Fred's `feature/tall`) as our remote-tracking names of the same name (`fred/feature/tall`), we'll be able to do:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to fred-pr-123 fred/feature/tall
```

for instance.

#### A bit of craziness in upstreams

Here there is a kink in the system, though.  Fortunately you mostly don't need to care about it.  Unfortunately, GitHub's naming scheme for Pull Requests may make you care about it, depending on how much you care to care about it.  (Ahem.)  Anyway: the *branch's name as seen on the upstream* isn't required to match the *remote-tracking name you use*.

What does all this mean?  Well, we have to go to the *mechanism* here.  When you run:

```
git fetch fred
```

your Git will read your repository's configuration to find the `remote.fred.fetch` settings.  These control *what gets fetched*, and the *standard* setting is:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/fred/*
```

This is a *refspec*.  It starts with a leading plus sign `+`, which means *force:* your remote-tracking names will be forcibly updated, so that if Fred rebased one of his branches, you'll pick up the rebase, for instance.  Then it lists `refs/heads/*` as the *source* part of the refspec, telling your Git *get all of his branches*.  It lists `refs/remotes/fred/*` as the *destination* part of the refspec, telling your Git *change those branch names into my remote-tracking names*.  This adds `fred/` in front of each name, and also puts them in `refs/remotes/`, so that they are remote-tracking names and are associated with your remote `fred` and not any other remote.  This way you can add `barney`, `wilma`, and `betty` as three more remotes, if that's appropriate, and you'll keep all their branches distinct in your remote-tracking names.

So that's the *normal* setup.  But the `remote.fred.fetch` refspec(s) **do not have to be normal**.  We can, if we like, write:

```
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/fred/scooby
+refs/heads/hairy:refs/remotes/fred/shaggy
```

This is a "two-branch remote" (analogous to a single-branch remote, but listing two branches): we copy Fred's `master` to our remote-tracking name `fred/scooby`, and his `hairy` to our remote-tracking name `fred/shaggy`.  Why?  Just for [illustration](https://www.illustrationhistory.org/artists/hanna-barbera), really.  The `upstream` setting to refer to Fred's `hairy` is `fred/shaggy`, but it's made up of two parts: `fred` and `hairy`.

If you use `git branch --set-upstream-to`, you don't have to think about all this mapping forwards and backwards.  If you use `git config` or `git config --edit` to reach directly into your `.git/config` file to fiddle with upstream settings, you *will* see all this craziness.  If you keep the fetch refspec simple, the craziness disappears, though.

#### Why I covered the craziness at all

If you stick with `branch@{upstream}` to refer to the upstream of the given branch, and use `git branch --set-upstream-to` to *set* the upstream, you hide any craziness.  If you didn't *make* any craziness, there isn't any craziness to hide.  But here's the hitch: when someone sends you a pull request via GitHub, this appears in *your* repository under a ref built using PR number:

```
refs/pull/123/head
```

This is not a *branch* name.  It's not a *remote-tracking* name.  It's a name GitHub made up.  If you want to get this commit from *your* GitHub fork, rather than from Fred's, you can do that:

```
git fetch origin refs/pull/123/head:refs/heads/pr-123
```

This will create, in your local repository, a *branch* named `pr-123` (`refs/heads/pr-123`) that names the *commit* that Fred wants you to put in.  That commit might have the name `refs/heads/feature/tall` in *Fred's* fork, but it has the name `refs/pull/123/head` in *your* fork.

Some people like to automatically create `pr/number` *branches* in their own repositories based on PRs made to their GitHub fork, and you can do that easily by adding another fetch refspec:

```
+refs/pull/*/head:refs/heads/pr-*
```

Your Git will take your GitHub fork's `refs/pull/*/head`, match the `*` part up to the PR number, and copy that to your own repository as `refs/heads/pr-whatever`.

(I don't like to do this automatically myself as it can create a lot of branches.  Note that old versions of Git can't handle `pr-*` here and require instead `pr/*` or similar.  Either way you'll probably want to set `fetch.prune` to `true` too, if you haven't already done that.)

If you *do* do this, you're letting some of the craziness show through.  You literally *can't* push to the `refs/pull` namespace, so it isn't a big problem, but you'll see weirdness.  Because of this dual mapping trick, this also means you can't name *your own* fork's branches `pr-*`: try it, and the craziness shines blindingly bright.  (The mappings stop being one-to-one onto / bijective / invertible, but they need to be.)

#### Multiple remotes and triangular workflows

If you choose to fetch from Fred's fork directly, and you have multiple remotes now (`fred` and `origin`), you will:

- fetch from Fred's fork;
- maybe do something to adjust the commits; and
- push to your fork.

This is, by definition, what Git calls a triangular workflow.  To make it easier, Git allows you to set separate fetch and push remotes.  You can do this overall, or per-branch.

Note that you may lose some features.  For instance, if there's both an `origin/feature/tall` *and* a `fred/feature/tall` and you have no `feature/tall` branch in your own repository yet, and you run:

```
git checkout feature/tall
```

you might expect the DWIM feature to kick in here: your Git will notice that you don't have a `feature/tall` so it will *create* it from `origin/feature/tall`, with the upstream pre-set.  But this doesn't work when there are *two* matches, and now there are two matches.

Modern Git has a new workaround, the *preferred remote* setting in `checkout.defaultRemote`.  If your Git is older, you can upgrade, or you can use `git checkout -t` or `git switch -t`:

```
git checkout -t origin/feature/tall
```

will create `feature/tall` from `origin/feature/tall` by stripping the remote part from the upstream.  The upstream is set from the name you listed.

You may also find that `git push`'s `push.default` default of `simple` becomes constraining.  The `current` setting may be more suitable for you.  This is all a matter of taste anyway though.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I've learnt a lot from it. Can you confirm that there is no way to use an url directly in "git branch -u"?

Comment: Yes: an upstream can only be set when using a remote. A URL is not a remote.