# Git pull from two different branches in two different repositories into one local branch

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull, git-remote

I cloned a Git repo locally--call it A.  This repo A has a branch named aaa.  I created a new local branch--bbb.  I then created a new GitHub repo (empty)--call it B--and pushed bbb to B.  Next, I changed the origin of my local repository to point to B.  I also then added a remote named "upstream" to my local repository that points to back to the original source, A.  I set the "push" url of this upstream remote to be something bogus ("no-pushing") since I never want to accidentally *push* from my local repo back to A.  I only want to *pull* from A into my local repo.
[image]

During a transition period, some developers will be committing changes to A/aaa.  Others are committing changes to B/bbb.

I want to be able to *pull* changes from A/aaa into my local **bbb** branch and then *push* those to B/bbb so that the code on B will have all of the changes from the team committing to A as well as all of the change from the team committing to B.  I also want to pull changes from B/bbb into my local bbb branch.  Essentially, I want to use my local repo as a bridge between the two temporarily until we stop using A at some future point.

**What git commands can I run to accomplish this?** (and what are each of the commands doing so I am not just blinding copying commands)

So far nothing I have tried has worked, and I think I must be missing some key element in my understanding.

Comment: A local repository can have two or more origins. Why not just set both sources as the origin, `git pull` from both (resolving any conflicts manually), then `git push` back to `B`?

Comment: That is what I thought I did.  I have [multiple remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690868/230055).  I suspect it the branch name differences that are causing me to not see the changes from A after I do a `git pull`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I removed the remote named "upstream" and re-added it with a different name just to repeat the steps from scratch.  These are the commands I used that worked:

```
git remote add A_upstream <<url_to_git_repo>>
git remote remove upstream
git remote set-url --push A_upstream no-pushing
git fetch --all
git checkout bbb
git merge A_upstream/aaa
git pull origin
git push origin
```

The first command added a new remote for A.  The next command removed the prior remote, and then in the next step I again set the push URL for the new remote to something bogus since I only want to pull from A.  Next, the `fetch --all` got everything from A and B, and then I merged the changes from the `aaa` branch into my local `bbb` branch with the next command.  The `pull` from origin ensured I was up to date with the commits in `bbb`, then the `push` to origin ensured the changes I had gotten from `aaa` went to B.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to pull changes from A/aaa into my local bbb branch and then push those to B/bbb so that the code on B will have all of the changes from the team committing to A as well as all of the change from the team committing to B

You can make sure:

- the upstream branch of `bbb` is `A/aaa`
- the push branch is `B/bbb` (as done in "[How to set up branches with different pull/push upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45644092/6309)")

```sh
cd /path/to/local
git switch bbb
git branch -u A/aaa bbb
git push -u B bbb
```