# How to configure a default pull repo?

Tags: git

I have multiple clones of the same remote repo. In order to decrease download time and (hopefully) increase pull speed, one of the clones is read only.

I would like to configure the other clones to pull from the read-only clone by default. Ideally, the read-only can be named `ro` and the remote repo that'll be pushed to can continue to be called `origin`.

Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45638858/3216427

Comment: @joanis, that one is about per-branch, not per-clone.

Comment: The question is, but isn't this answer about the whole repo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45644092/3216427

Comment: That may be but when someone is looking for an answer, they're going to match by the question they have. If that answer is applicable to this question, it can be added as an answer here. FWIW, that answer mentions branches a lot which, even if it does answer this question, includes a bunch of noise not relevant to this question.

Comment: Hey, I didn't actually flag your question as a duplicate. I'm just trying to help, if it's not helpful, them my apologies for the noise.

Comment: I understand you haven't flagged it as an actual duplicate and want to help. I'm addressing the concern that it could be a duplicate and how best to go about it if it were a duplicate.

Comment: Sounds good, point taken.

Comment: Thanks for raising the potential issue. It's definitely worth investigating.